# Unable to get entitlements for client task

Tags: kif-framework, kif

I'm using the next pod file:

platform :ios, "6.0"

target "Tests", :exclusive => true do
  pod 'KIF', :head
end

After pods was successfully updated, i try to run 1 test method but after project build operation i receive next message in the XCode console:  Unable to get entitlements for client task. Error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=-1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (POSIX error -1 - Unknown error: -1)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow; this is certainly a good place to come for help from those with more experience. I think your post might benefit from a small edit to make it crystal clear that you want some help with getting rid of the error message. I'm completely unfamiliar with ios and don't recognise any of the technical terms you use - but how do you know that pods was successfully installed? It seems that you can't use it, so maybe the problem is that it hasn't been installed OK. Just a random thought - good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Update pod file row to: pod 'KIF/OCUnit', :head